# How do you keep yourself from being hungry all the time and snacking?

Tags: health, food

I started working out again because I'm getting in bad shape and I can feel how out of shape I've gotten the past few months. I signed up at the gym and have no problem going there to workout after work or on my free time. My problem is, I live alone at an apartment because I had to relocate for work and I keep wanting to snack all the time. I find myself looking through the fridge constantly. How do you keep yourself from being hungry all the time and snacking? I greatly appreciate the answers.

Comment: Great question!

Comment: FYI: http://www.dailymail.co.uk/health/article-2906356/Are-emotional-eater-constant-craver-feaster-interactive-test-discover-diet-best-help-shed-pounds-off.html

Answer (score 1):

Avoiding snacking and overeating in general has always been one of the toughest things for me. Here are some things I do that help.

- Drink a glass of water each time you go to the fridge, a lot of the time you're thirsty without knowing it. This actually ends up helping a TON.
- If you're in the kitchen out of boredom instead of real hunger (I would snack to pass the time and wander in there), try brushing your teeth instead of eating something. The minty flavor makes eating reasonably undesirable.
- Buy some extremely low-calorie snacks you can resort to. I have light microwave popcorn that's 100 calories a bag, puffed oatmeal crackers that are 35-50 each (and relatively large), celery, salsa (no normal chips, use the crackers or celery), or the cheap ice-popsicles are all great things to have on hand.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is I eat big meals for lunch and dinner. The total calorie intake is huge, but it comes from healthy foods like olive oil, whole grain pasta, whole grain bread. If you eat only healthy foods, you'll recuperate from exercise better, you become stronger, allowing you to exercise harder. You'll achieve equilibrium between calorie use and calorie intake at a higher level while your weight will have a healthy, normal value.

So, I would suggest you stop eating any form of junk foods. No more French fries, hamburgers, cookies, cakes, ice creams, pizza's etc. etc. That will force you to get your calories from foods like brown rice, whole grain pasta, vegetables fried in olive oil etc. etc. You can then eat as much as you need to not get feel hungry at all, the amount of vitamins and minerals you get in will increase a lot, maybe by a factor 2 or 3.

Answer (score 0):

- Do not keep junk food in your fridge
- Keep Fruits and salad in you fridge
- Drink hell lot of water

I do this